# Using tcolorbox to get a full width bibliography in the symmetric tufte-book class

Tags: bibtex, tcolorbox, double-sided, tufte, fullwidth

I have written my document using the `tufte-book` document class with `twoside` and `symmetric` option. When I include my bibliography into the document only the main text column is used which is a colossal waste of space. I would therefore like to stretch it to the full width of the page.

Since the *fullwidth* package is not working properly in combination with the symmetric option of the `tufte-book`, I already tried to put the bibliography into an `mdframed` environment without success (in fact, it created an infinite loop). I am currently trying with a breakable `tcolorbox` which already yields a result I can live with, except that it inserts an additional page before the start of the bibliography.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,symmetric,nobib,notoc]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]~\cite{Paper1,Paper2,Paper3,Paper4,Paper5}
\cleardoublepage

\huge

% This is how the bibliography looks like without treatment
% Pretty ugly because there is a lot of wasted space
\bibliography{testbib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\cleardoublepage

% Try to eliminate margins by putting bibliography into a tcolorbox
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, enforce breakable, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage, notitle after break, vfill before first]
\bibliography{testbib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

it uses the following bibliography testbib.bib

```
@article{Paper1, title = {Broken Symmetry and the Mass of Gauge Vector Mesons}, author = {Englert, F. and Brout, R.}, journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.}, volume = {13}, issue = {9}, pages = {321-323}, year = {1964}}
@article{Paper2, title = {Broken symmetries, massless particles and gauge fields}, author = {Peter W. Higgs}, journal = {Phys. Lett.}, volume = {12}, issue = {2}, pages = {132-133}, year = {1964}}
@article{Paper3, title = {Broken Symmetries and the Masses of Gauge Bosons}, author = {Higgs, Peter W.}, journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.}, volume = {13}, issue = {16}, pages = {508-509}, year = {1964}}
@article{Paper4, author = "Guralnik, G. S. and Hagen, C. R. and Kibble, T. W. B.", title = "{Global Conservation Laws and Massless Particles}", journal = "Phys. Rev. Lett.", volume = "13", year = "1964", pages = "585-587"}
@techreport{Paper5, title = "{Observation of an Excess of Events in the Search for the Standard Model Higgs boson with the ATLAS detector at the LHC}", institution = "CERN", collaboration = "ATLAS Collaboration", address = "Geneva", number = "ATLAS-CONF-2012-093", month = "Jul", year = "2012"}
```

I have left the `tcolorbox` visible so you can see the break in the box which results in a new page. How can I suppress this break and force the start of the bibliography on the previous page (i.e. page 5 in the example)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the `\huge` command really necessary there? Removing that and using `\tcolorboxenvironment{thebibliography}{options as in the post}` will not provide a break before the bibliography heading

Comment: Yes, the problem only shows up when the bibliography stretches over multiple pages. I could have added more references instead of the \huge

Comment: The real culprit seems to be `\chapter*` in `\thebibliography`

Comment: Removing the '\huge' thus hides the problem. The solution I try to find is a full width bibliography including (several) page breaks without the initial empty page.

Comment: It is indeed due to the `\chapter*`. The same behaviour can be reproduced by putting a chapter beginning within the box. Nevertheless, I don't know how to prevet this from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\let\clearpage\relax` for the `before upper` code will prevent a premature break of the `tcolorbox` just before `\chapter*` from `thebibliography` occurs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,symmetric,nobib,notoc]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]~\cite{Paper1,Paper2,Paper3,Paper4,Paper5}


% This is how the bibliography looks like without treatment
% Pretty ugly because there is a lot of wasted space
%\bibliography{testbib}{}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}


% Try to eliminate margins by putting bibliography into a tcolorbox



\tcolorboxenvironment{thebibliography}{
  enhanced, 
  breakable, 
  check odd page, 
  toggle left and right, 
  grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, 
  toggle enlargement=evenpage, 
  notitle after break,
  nobeforeafter,
  sharp corners,
  top=0pt,
  before upper={\let\clearpage\relax},
  fontupper=\Huge}


\bibliography{testbib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

[image]