# Issue with the tcolorbox package and the table of content - two useless pages appear before with void boxes

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I am struggling to put a background to my table of content with the `tcolorbox` package. Unfortunately, there are two or one page (depending on the `twoside` option) with a small void box.

I put you a dummy code here if you can figure out how to make the table of content start without generating these void boxes.

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}



\title{Debugging}
\author{Its me...}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Color2}{RGB}{204, 225, 218} %light green
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
   % frame code={}
    %center title,
    %left=10pt,
    %right=10pt,
    top=10pt,
    %bottom=10pt,
    colback=Color2!30,
    colframe=white,
    width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
    boxsep=10pt,
    arc=8pt,
    %outer arc=0pt,
    breakable,
    }




\begin{document}
\maketitle

%% PROBLEM APPEARS HERE

\newpage
\begin{tcolorbox}
\tableofcontents
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage


% DUMMY SECTIONS FOR GENERATING TOC GREATER THAN ONE PAGE
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}





\end{document}
```

Comment: It is basically the same issue as reported here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396660/using-tcolorbox-to-get-a-full-width-bibliography-in-the-symmetric-tufte-book-cla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\tableofcontents` uses `\chapter*{\contentsname}`, there is a `\clearpage` involved with `\tableofcontents. Breakable`tcolorbox` environments cannot really cope with this.

A possible solution is to say `before upper=\let\clearpage\relax`, as long as no floats appear in the `ToC` (which is a rather unlikely place for floats).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}



\title{Debugging}
\author{Its me...}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Color2}{RGB}{204, 225, 218} %light green
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
   % frame code={}
    %center title,
    %left=10pt,
    %right=10pt,
    top=10pt,
    %bottom=10pt,
    colback=Color2!30,
    colframe=white,
%    width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
    boxsep=10pt,
    arc=8pt,
    %outer arc=0pt,
    breakable,
    }




\begin{document}
\maketitle

%% PROBLEM APPEARS HERE

\newpage
\begin{tcolorbox}[before upper={\let\clearpage\relax}]
\tableofcontents
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage


% DUMMY SECTIONS FOR GENERATING TOC GREATER THAN ONE PAGE
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Another option is to modify the `\tableofcontents` command.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: @Willi: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!